# trying to remove comma from input but it deletes a part with the comma

Tags: python, testing, project

```
import re
text=input()
sentences = text.split('.')
result = []
word_count = 1
for sentence in sentences:
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        if word[0].isupper() and word != words[0]:
            result.append((word,word_count))
        word_count+=1
        
if len(result)>0:
    for word,index in result:
        text.replace(',','')
        print(f"{index}:{word}")
        
else:
    print('None')

print(result)
```

`
this is the code and it should get a sentence and show me index words

```
 The Massachusetts Institute of Technology is a private research university located in Cambridge, Massachusetts, United States.
2:Massachusetts
3:Institute
5:Technology
13:Cambridge,
14:Massachusetts,
15:United
16:States
[('Massachusetts', 2), ('Institute', 3), ('Technology', 5), ('Cambridge,', 13), ('Massachusetts,', 14), ('United', 15), ('States', 16)]
```

but the output is with comma and trying to remove commas it deletes the part( , Massachusetts, United )

```
2:Massachusetts
3:Institute
5:Technology
13:Cambridge
16:States.
[('Massachusetts', 2), ('Institute', 3), ('Technology', 5), ('Cambridge', 13), ('States.', 16)]
```

pls help I cant figure it out

tried replace remove regex re.split but it didn't work.

Comment: Replace `Massachusetts,` with `Massachusetts`?

Comment: this is an online test so the sentence is created by computer and not me

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are looking for. Perhaps changing `text.replace(',','')` to `word = word.replace(',','')`?

Comment: The replace isn't the problem (not least because you're calling replace on `text`), the word isn't even in you result list. Try debugging the loop where you populate `result`. *(Add `print('Parsing; {word!r}')` to the start of the `for word in words` loop...)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use regular expressions, you would have an easier time using findall than split.  findall will allow you extract the words directly without having to worry about separators or punctuation:

```
import re
index  = 0
result = []
for sentence in text.split("."): 
    for i,word in enumerate(re.findall("\w+",sentence)):
        index += 1
        if i and word[0].isupper():
            result += [(word,index)]
            
for w,i in result:
    print(i,":",w)

2 : Massachusetts
3 : Institute
5 : Technology
13 : Cambridge
14 : Massachusetts
15 : United
16 : States
```

*Note that, if you want your word index to restart at the beginning of each new sentence, you will have to initialize it inside the first loop rather than outside of it (or simply use `i`)*